# Convert radians into degree in IOS

Tags: ios

Hi friends I need to convert the radian value into Degree.  Below code is to get the radians

```
UIView *view = [self view];
   CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX([view bounds]), CGRectGetMidY([view bounds]));
   CGPoint currentTouchPoint = [touch locationInView:view];
   CGPoint previousTouchPoint = [touch previousLocationInView:view];

   CGFloat angleInRadians = atan2f(currentTouchPoint.y - center.y, currentTouchPoint.x - center.x) - atan2f(previousTouchPoint.y - center.y, previousTouchPoint.x - center.x);
```

This is was done in **touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event**.  But I need to convert this **angleInRadians** CGFloat value into degree like **45.0 deg**.  How can I achieve this.

I have tried the below methods, but I can't find the solution:

1. `#define RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(radians) ((radians) * (180.0 / M_PI))`
2. `CGFloat RadiansToDegrees(CGFloat radians) { return radians * 180 / M_PI; };`

Comment: #define RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(radians) ((radians) * (180.0 / M_PI)) works, just tried it

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution.. In my code I get angle only for current move not the current angle for my view.

```
CGFloat radians = atan2f(yourView.transform.b, yourView.transform.a); 
CGFloat degrees = radians * (180 / M_PI);
```

Use this code I got my solution.

Thanks for all who spend time for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
 // Use the following macro in your code to convert radians to degrees:

 #define RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(radians) ((radians) * (180.0 / M_PI))
 NSLog(@"Output radians as degrees: %f", RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(0.584));
```

Otherwise try `(acos(0)*180)/M_PI`

Note: Using `acosf(float)` instead of `acosf(double)`

Answer (score 0):

`(radians) * (180.0 / M_PI)` which always gives to degree, there might be wrong in the calculation try below code might be help u..

```
 - (double)getTheAngleBetweenPoint:(CGPoint)point1 andPoint:(CGPoint)point2
  {
    double angle;
    CGFloat delta_y = point2.y - point1.y;
    if(delta_y < 0)
    {
       delta_y *= -1;
    }
    CGFloat delta_x = point2.x  - point1.x;
    if(delta_x < 0)
    {
      delta_x *= -1;
    }

    angle = atan2(delta_y, delta_x) * (180/M_PI) ; //returning the tan of the angle in degree

   return angle;
 }


 - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
     UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
     UIView *view = [touch view];
     double angle = [self getTheAngleBetweenPoint:[touch locationInView:view] andPoint:[touch previousLocationInView:view]];
     NSLog(@"%f",angle);

}
```